# Online Linux Bash Demo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, html

I wanted to demo a few basic Linux shell (bash) commands to someone. I don't want to go through the whole routine of installing a Linux VM on my system just to be able to do that. I was just wondering if there is some online webpage where I can do that? Something like [try MongoDB](http://try.mongodb.org/) online.

Would be grateful for any pointers. Thanks!

Comment: What OS do you happen to have?

Comment: Such a facility might be easily abused (at least to overload the web service) so is not easy to get right. The simplest way to show the shell is to `ssh` to some existing machine on which you have a legitimate shell account.

Comment: (@Basile) Hmm, yes, I agree, however a non-root thingy would be great.

Comment: @choroba, any OS flavor would do so long as it has a bash shell. Just want to demo some simple cp and mv commands and so on.

Comment: That was not the point of my question. If you have MSWin, just install Cygwin.

Comment: Oh yes, I do have Windows 7... Cygwin actually may make sense. However, would still be great to have something like an actual, simulated shell. (Sorry about using the Oxymoron ;) )

Comment: Even a non-root bash access is a way for significant damage (like a fork bomb in bash)

Comment: Question should have been moved to "Super User" Stack not just closed.

Comment: @choroba Late comment on closed question but Cygwin has different versions of most programs, e.g. `ps`, which have different syntax to the usual versions. So it may not run commands properly.

Answer (score 5):

I know is this one, it is a Javascript PC Emulator

http://bellard.org/jslinux/

Comment: Hi @fedorqui, that looks good! I tried a couple of things like mkdir, ''touch''ing a file, ls, and so forth, seems to be working great. I think that may actually do the trick! Thanks so much!

Comment: Good to read it helped you, @Najeeb : )

Answer (score 3):

This site does a lot of languages in the browser:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php

Comment: Hi @Stanley, thanks so much for this! Looks quite interesting.

Comment: This has moved here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a FreeBSD one, should be good enough for bash stuff, see http://cb.vu/

Comment: Hi @cartman, this looks great too! Will give it a shot first thing in the morning. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Fabrice Bellard [JSLinux](http://bellard.org/jslinux/) is a full Linux PC emulator running in a Javascript-capable recent browser and it gives a shell (probably not a full `bash` just a `busybox`)

Comment: It wasn't me the one downvoting! It may be for repeating answer, I had already linked the page... don't know.

Comment: The downvote was uncalled for. Wish I could upvote it, however don't have enough points for that :( @Basile, I just want some rudimentary commands to make the newbie comfortable. So I guess that should work very well for my situation. Thanks! :)

Comment: Should be on Super User not Stackoverflow.